# Using RotateAround() subsequently also rotates the 3. axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to rotate the camera around a character by moving the mouse and tried this:

```cs
m_Cam.RotateAround(m_Character.transform.localPosition, Vector3.up, 
                   Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")* rotationSpeedY * Time.deltaTime);
m_Cam.RotateAround(m_Character.transform.localPosition, Vector3.right,
                   Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSpeedX * Time.deltaTime);
```

But if I do both lines of code, it also rotates the z-axis. If I just use either, they work as intended. So the first one rotates the camera horizontally and the second one rotates the camera vertically. But if I enable both they still do that, but also the z-axis is rotated and I don´t know why.

They´re called in FixedUpdate().

Can someone please explain hwy this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: If you rotate on more than one axis, all three will move.

Comment: If the answer below helped you, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do both rotations on a real object you will note that indeed it will be shifted also on its local Z axis ;) (In the Inspector you see the local Euler axis.)

This is exactly what happens if you perform both rotations on **global** world space axis.

As solution you would need to make sure that the Y axis is rotated in **global** space, while the X is rotated in **local** space of the camera.

You could achieve that by using the `m_Cam`s **local X axis** for the rotation in X

```
//                                                      | global Y axis
//                                                      V
m_Cam.RotateAround(m_Character.transform.localPosition, Vector3.up, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")* rotationSpeedY * Time.deltaTime);
//                                                      | local X axis
//                                                      V
m_Cam.RotateAround(m_Character.transform.localPosition, m_Cam.right, Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSpeedX * Time.deltaTime);
```